# How to get all the TextBox names of a windows form when the name of each TextBox is changing

Tags: c#, winforms

When I run my form, I just want to get the names of all the text boxes of the active form at run time in a label.

I searched a lot but all I found was something in which they haven't changed the names of text boxes.

```
var allTexboxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
var sortedTextBoxes = allTexboxes
                     .Where(i => String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Text))
                     .OrderBy(i => i.Name)
                     .ToArray();
```

Comment: Do you mean all the TextBox controls in your current Form? All the TextBoxes which are descendant of that Form (their parent can also be another Container) or just the direct children (Controls that are directly positioned on the Form's *surface*)? What does *through on run time in a label* mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your code example and explanation of what you want is confusing. If you want an array of all textbox names within a form:

```
string[] GetTexBoxNames()
{
    var names =new List<string>();
    for each(var c in this.Controls)
    {
        if(c is TextBox)
        {
            names.Add(c.name);
        }
    }
    return names.ToArray();
}
```

The phrase "this" is referring to the form. If you want to do this calculation from oitside the form, replace that keyword with a variable referencing it.

You can also use a lamda expression to get all textbox in an arrayin a single expression..

```
var textBoxNames = this.Controls
                 .Where(i => i is TextBox)
                 .ToArray();
```

Another thing you might want is a dictionary of all TextBoxes, with their names as the keys. You don't need this unless lookup speed is critical, because you can use a lamda to lookup a textbox in the final array which is slower than a dictionary lookup. You can use a simple for loop to go over every textbox and let them in a dictionary by name.

You probably can edit this code to suit your purpose if I got you wrong. Please clarify and I will update this answer as well.